# ssis 2008, delete contents from excel

Tags: ssis

im using SSIS for SQL Server 2008.

My SSIS package grabs data from sql and exports it to an excel file. But everytime it does this I want new data on the excel.

The problem right now is, If i execute the package more than one time I will have the old data plus the new one on the excel file. I only want the new data displayed.

On the SSIS, on the Control Flow tab I have an Data Flow task. On the Data Flow tab I have an OLEDB source and an Excel Destination in order to put the data on the excel.

So im thinking on deleting the contents from the excel on the SSIS every time before the data gets inserted on the excel.

The excel file has an image, a title and the column names. I want these data to stay.

But I want the data from the rows deleted.

How can I do this?

Thanks...

Comment: Im trying to do the following: Put a file system task and then copy the excel file to another location, so i will have a new excel file(file2), and copy the data there. Then the next time it runs i can delete the new file2 when the package starts, and the process starts all over again.........Is this a good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. What I did was to make a copy of the file and load the data on the new file, and everytime the ssis loads it overwrites the file, so I always have new data..........Thanks!!